# Filter data.table using inequalities and variable column names

Tags: r, data.table, inequality

I have a `data.table` that i want to filter based on some inequality criteria:

```
dt <- data.table(A=letters[1:3], B=2:4)
dt
#    A B
# 1: a 2
# 2: b 3
# 3: c 4

dt[B>2]
#    A B
# 1: b 3
# 2: c 4
```

The above works well as a vector scan solution. But I can't work out how to combine this with variable names for the columns:

```
mycol <- "B"
dt[mycol > 2]
#    A B      // Nothing has changed
# 1: a 2
# 2: b 3
# 3: c 4
```

How do I work around this? I know I can use binary search by setting keys using `setkeyv(dt, mycol)` but I can't see a way of doing a binary search based on some inequality criteria.

Comment: does `get(mycol)` work?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Yes. That would be the function I was missing...

Comment: You can go ahead and post that as the answer if you like.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Only if you really don't want to post your answer yourself :)

Comment: Also this works `dt[eval(parse(text=mycol)) > 2]`

Comment: Guys, these are answers! Post them as such!

Comment: @digEmAll  the use of `eval(parse())` is strictly verboten per `fortune(106)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, then,
Use `get(mycol)`  because you want the argument to `dt[` to be the contents of the object "mycol" .  I believe `dt[mycol ...]` looks for a "mycol" thingie in the `data.table` object itself, of which of course there is no such animal.

Comment: This saved me.  But even if you do `dt['B' > 2]`, you have to do `dt[get('B') > 2]`.  Kind of annoying/seems like column references should work as a string.

Comment: @wordsforthewise  Thanks for the correction.  I have to admit I haven't looked at this problem in the last 4 years!

Answer (score 5):

There is an accesor function provided for this. `j` is evaluated in the frame of `X`, i.e. your `data.table`, *unless* you specify `with = FALSE`. This would be the *canonical* way of doing this.

```
dt[ , mycol , with = FALSE ]
   B
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
```

Return column, logical comparison, subset rows...

```
dt[ c( dt[ , mycol , with = FALSE ] > 2 ) ]
```

Comment: @Mattrition see update. I don't like `get` because you might encounter some unexpected behaviour evaluating this in some nested calling environments. I'd jsut figure that `with = FALSE` would be provided for a reason.

Comment: Ok, your answer now provides a different an alternative solution, so thank you. A third alternative I found is `dt[dt[[mycol]] > 2]`.

Comment: @Mattrition *<facepalm>* that seems the most obvious. You should answer your own question with that.

Comment: I really dislike both this and the `[[` alternatives, because they are a lot more error prone (since you have to specify the `data.table` name twice)

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to use `]]` to retrieve B as a vector, and subset using this:

```
dt[dt[[mycol]] > 2]
```